# Correct way to handle mixed DBCS and SBCS stream in java?

Tags: java, character-encoding

DBCS - Double Byte Character String (e.g.Japanese)
SBCS - Single Byte Character String (e.g. English)

When I receive InputStream from server, I don't know how handle this situation in Java...

Comment: Your server is sending character data in multiple encodings?

Comment: only bytes are coming from server, if i consider bytes as dbcs(EUC-JP) englsh is shown as junk, if i consider sbcs(UTF-8) japanese showing as junk

Comment: So you've tried 2 encodings and neither work. You can either continue trying different encodings, or ask the developer of the server which encoding they use.

Comment: so is there any way to separate dbcs and sbcs in single mixed stream??

Comment: Why would they combine two encodings? I think you're assuming too much.  You realize that there are multiple single and 2-byte encodings, right?

Comment: Formatting and spelling

Comment: You don't know how to handle it in Java? Do you know how to handle it in another language? The problem here doesn't seem to be platform specific, but inherent in the mixture of encodings. Consider posting a short sample of the raw stream, encoded with Base-64 or hexadecimal to avoid any character decoding issues.

Comment: @erickson sorry, here how to handle it in java, i mean i need to implement in java, i doesnt mean i know this handling in another language.. I actually need to know is there already any formal way to handle the stream which contains dbcs(Japanese) and sbcs(English).. sorry if i'm not clear..

Comment: Yes, there are a number of variable width encodings that efficiently handle a mix of Japanese and English. If you posted a sample of the raw bytes before decoding (using base-64 or hexadecimal representation of the bytes), we might find that one of these encodings was used instead of EUC-JP.